# Nature of the function

Tags: general-topology

I want to check the nature of the function $f:\mathbb{R}\to \mathbb{R}$ defined by $f(x)=x+\sin x$ for all $x\in \mathbb{R}$, where cofinite topology is considered in $\mathbb{R}$.

Is this function strictly increasing? If so, then it is one-one and so continuous. But I am not sure? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Remember your calculus!! How do you check that a function is increasing?

Comment: If $f^{'}(x)>0$, then $f$ is strictly increasing...but in this case $f^{'}(x)=0$ for all multiples of $\pi$. Thus $f$ is not strictly increasing. So, is it one-one?

Comment: This is a pretty easy one to figure out... maybe just a tad more than cookbook calculus may be required. If you are learning topology, then surely you can do this.

Answer (score 1):

I suppose I should go ahead and answer this.

Yes, the function is strictly increasing, i.e., $x < y$ implies $x + \sin(x) < y + \sin(y)$. In the case where the interval $(x, y)$ contains no odd multiple of $\pi$, this is clear from the mean value theorem, since $f'(t) = 1 + \cos(t) > 0$ for $x < t < y$. Otherwise, we can let $x_1, \ldots x_n$ enumerate the odd multiples of $\pi$ in $(x, y)$, and use the exact same argument to conclude

$$f(x) < f(x_1) < f(x_2) < \ldots < f(x_n) < f(y)$$

by restricting attention to each of the intervals $(x, x_1), (x_1, x_2), \ldots, (x_{n-1}, x_n), (x_n, y)$.